# Efficiently determining surface intersections along a line segment

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, curves-and-surfaces

### Background

In general, I know how to determine the points of intersection between a surface and a line. In my case, I may have a large number of defined surfaces that may (or may not) intersect each other and may (or may not) be located in close proximity to each other. I would like to determine all the points of intersection with a line segment and any of the surfaces. Programmatically, I can loop through all surfaces to determine existing intersections with the line. However, as the number of surfaces grows this can become not only computationally expensive, but also intuitively inefficient if I know the trajectory and endpoint of the line. That is, I know that if the surface is far from the trajectory of the line or that the line segment ends well before reaching another surface along it's trajectory, there should be no need for me to even check for an intersection. For the former, determining the distance from the line trajectory and the surface to make this comparison is equally (or more) expensive than to just check for the intersection. For the latter, I'm not sure how to "terminate" evaluations for intersections.

### Question

What sort of algorithm or mathematical concepts would allow me to *efficiently* search for surface intersections along a line segment based on the problems identified above?

Comment: Look up R-Trees

Comment: @J.J.Green I was thinking about doing something like this but wasn't sure how to formalize it - looks like someone already did. Thanks for the find! I'll research how it fits into my application

Comment: Outline: put each of your surfaces in an rectangle and create an R-tree index (in roughly n log(n) time/space), put each line in a rectangle and query the tree, it will give you the surface-rectangles which intersect the line-rectangle (in roughly log(n) time).  Then check for real intersections of those.  Depending on the problem, chop the line into smaller segments for smaller bounding rectangles.